# Error: Cannot find module '/bin' in lambda deployment issue with serverless framework

Tags: webpack, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, mysql2

I've encountered following error message after deployment lambda function with serverless framework integrated with webpack. It was working perfectly when I deployed without webpack. Please help me how to resolve that issue. Thanks.

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module '/bin'",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '/bin'",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
    "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
    "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)",
    "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)",
    "    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)"
  ]
}
```

Here is my part of **serverless.yaml**

```
custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules:
      forceExclude:
        - aws-sdk
        - mysql2
        - sequelize
        - path
```

and webpack.config.js is as follow:

const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");

```
module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: "node",
  // Generate sourcemaps for proper error messages
  devtool: 'source-map',
  // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
  // we exclude all node dependencies
  externals: [
    'aws-sdk',
    'mysql2',
    'sequelize',
    'path',
  ],
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? "development" : "production",
  optimization: {
    // We do not want to minimize our code.
    minimize: false
  },
  performance: {
    // Turn off size warnings for entry points
    hints: false
  },
  // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: It's hard to tell unless you show us how `bin` is imported in your `UserFunction.js`.

Comment: @NoelLlevares no, i didn't import `bin` to my project.

Comment: If you didn't import it directly, one of your dependencies (or sub-dependencies) did. You have to find which one and add that as one of your externals in webpack and serverless configs.